# How to implement screen recording with audio in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, screen-recording

I have a requirement where I have screen recording with audio as well. I have done some Google and got to know about how can we implement screen recording but I am wondering how to save audio while screen recording.

Is there any possibility that we can merge the video and audio and then save the final data on disk?

But I am not sure that will it be feasible because there will be difference in syncing with audio and video frames.

For screen recording I got a link of **ScreenCaptureView** which actually lets you save the screen recording.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS9 there is [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-605/) it's a framework that can be used to make screen recording on video games. It seems that you can use also for common screen capture.
For lower platforms it's a kind of big deal, video screen capturing exists but is a private framework ( I guess IOSurface). There are some work arounds as in this [project](https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder) , basically it starts to grab sigle screenshot and append them into a movie file, without audio

Comment: Thanks @andrea. Is this framework support for audio recording while doing screen recording ?

Comment: ReplayKit yes it does

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot @Andrea. I will integrate it and will let you know if anything comes up.